# WPF DevExpress Grid date filterstring

Tags: c#, wpf, datetime, grid, devexpress

I'm trying to apply filter parameters from a little form to a DevExpress grid.
I did this by binding the FilterString from the grid to a string in the ViewModel.

​currently I construct the filterstring as follows:
​

```
filterString += "[" + column.Header + "] >= '" 
                + ((DateTime)searchParameter).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") 
                + "' AND [" + column.Header + "] < '" 
                + ((DateTime)searchParameter).AddDays(1).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") 
                + "'";
```

in which the column header and field name come from the columnMap and the `searchParameter` is the date to filter on.

The filter is applied correctly and also shown in the bottom of the grid. You can also edit it, but only string values are shown in the
filter row at the top of the grid. Dates or Numbers aren't shown there.

How can I also get dates and numbers to show in the filter row if
I set a filterstring?

It currently looks like this when filtering on name (data edited out):
[image]

Comment: try using system default Date format by calling `((DateTime)searchParameter).ToShortDateString()` instead of `((DateTime)searchParameter).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")` . Maybe DX cannot understand your date correctly.

Comment: I tried some different formattings including that,but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you:

[GridColumn.FilterMode Property](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridColumnsGridColumn_FilterModetopic)

DX [suggests](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q552997) to set `GridColumn.FilterMode` property of the date column to `DisplayText`.

Comment: It's not really something I would want since you lose the dropdown, but it didn't work :(

Comment: @SebastiaanHoedeman could you post a screenshot of how the filter row currently looks like, without Date and Number values I mean?

Comment: I added a screenshot showing the name being filtered. As you can see the name is shown at the bottom and the filter row at the top. It's also editable by clicking the pencil in the bottom right corner, so everything works fine. For dates and numbers it's the same except that they don't show in the filter row at the top.

Comment: @SebastiaanHoedeman yes I see. And how would you like to specify dates in filter row? By editing text string like `2017-02-17` or by using DatePicker control? Or you are NOT going to allow user to change dates in filter row but just have them displayed as string?

Comment: Dates should be editable in the filter row by using a datepicker